# Element comparing in a column of an Array

Tags: c

Working on a function that checks columns elements, and counts the columns which consists of non matching elements in the specific column.

Here's the part of the function where problem is suppose to be:

( `j` - current column, `c` - totalRows, `i` - current row, `r` - totalRows, `k` - offset)

```
for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
{
  fail=0;
  for (i=0;i i < r; i++)
      {
      for(k=i+1; i < r; i++)
         {
         if(array[i][j]==array[k][j])
            {
            fail=1;
            break;
            }
          else
            {
            fail=0;
            }
         }
        if(fail==1)
         {
         break;
         }
    }
if(fail==0)
 {
 column++;
 }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?  What's the question?

Comment: Haha,my bad, the problem is that code itself has no errors it runs but the column sum is usually wrong, took it down by parts and this is how for I got, the problem must be  in these few lines!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the wrong variable in the `k` loop:

```
  for(k=i+1; i < r; i++)
```

You should be comparing and incrementing `k`, not `i`.

The code could be a little tidier, too:

```
for( j = 0; j < c; j++ )
{
    fail = 0;
    for( i = 0; i < r && !fail; i++ )
    {
        for( k = i+1; k < r; k++ )
        {
           if( array[i][j] == array[k][j] )
           {
              fail=1;
              break;
           }
        }
    }

    if( !fail ) column++;
}
```

Comment: Tried it before, and tried it again,
for (k=i+1; k<r; i++)
makes no difference.
If I understood your thought correctly.

Comment: I could swear that I tried k<r;k++ before as well, oh well. Big thanks man,saved me some time, I'll send you the happy thoughts!

Comment: Accepting the answer would probably be more useful than sending happy thoughts =)  You might want to review your other questions too.  You don't have a good track record of accepting answers, which will eventually lead to nobody wanting to answer your questions.

Comment: Kinda new to stackoverflow, was not aware of that accept answer option, fixed! Thanks again!

Comment: No worries.  You should read through the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/about) section.  You'll even get a badge for doing so, if you care about badges =)

Answer (score 0):

you said that the program is running correctly but the result is wrong. I think the fault is in this row:
    for (i=0;i i < r; i++)
it must be like this:
    for (i=0;i i < r-1; i++)
to avoid comparing the column with itself in the last iteration.